# Qt: Windows 10: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

**In Short:** I am trying to link my Qt5.5 to MySQL but it is not working.

**The long story** begins when I tried to use `MySQL` as in:

```
QSqlDatabase theDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

But when I run my application, I get the following messages:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
>
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

At this point, I looked online to see how to fix this.

Then I found on [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql) that I need to build the MySQL plugin. So, I followed the guidance:

1. I donwloaded `mysql-installer-community-5.7.19.0`
2. I tried to instal MySQL. However, during the installation, there was no `Libs & Include Files` Module to install !!
3. But I continued the installation and run MySQL57 succesfully as a service locally.
4. I could not of course build the plugin because there is not `sqldrivers` folder in my installed files.

I started looking all over the internet for solution. Then:

5. According to this [youtube answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0quVy31AOw4), I needed to copy `libmysql.dll` from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin` to `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`

I run my application, but again I have the same error !! So:

4. I copied the file `libmysql.dll` from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib` to the same location `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`,

However, again I have the same error.

I am now stuck, don't know what to do.

P.S.: I have sql in my .pro file in Qt-application

Comment: Maybe the most likely solution if all the scenario you have mentioned is to build Qt with you toolchain and produce `libmysql.dll` and trying using that one. Actually I faced this problem on GNU/Linux and rebuilding Qt solved my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the 32-bit version of libmysql.dll; check here for details: [qt 5.8 sql connection error:QMYSQL driver not loaded on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683438/qt-5-8-sql-connection-errorqmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-windows-10/45394110#45394110)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. it doesn't work though with 64-bit. Many thanks again

Answer (score 6):

My version is QT 5.11.1.  I met same problem.
I copied `libmysql.dll`

from

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib

to

> C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\mingw53_32\bin.

Finally,I succeeded.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for a solution for two days, and now it finally works.

Comment: This also worked for me! libmysql.dll has to go to the bin folder of qt installation.